# Representing Logical Operations in an OO manner with Java

Tags: java, csv, macros, boolean-logic, oop

My java program will allow the content of a csv file to be filtered based on a user defined logical operation. Data will be read from the content of two column csv file

```
left    right
5       10
2       6
```

and user will provide a logical condition operation on the command line referencing left and right. The program should filter to content of the csv files based on the outcome of the logical operation.

```
IF ((left < right) AND (left !=10)) THEN 5 ELSE right
```

I plan to represent the operation types as an enum

```
enum Operation
    >,
    <,
    ==,
    !=

 public boolean evaluate(int left,int right);
```

which would support an evaluate method. The specific logic for the operation would be implemented within the specific enum types.

A Condition interface would support methods to access the left operand, operation and right operand

```
interface Condition
{
    public int getLeft();
    public Operation();
    public int getRight();
}
```

For a AND case I would just maintain a list of Conditions and iterate over the list to ensure that all conditions are true. But how show i represent the IF THEN ELSE key words?

Answer (score 0):

Following your interface convention:

```
interface Conditional {
    public Condition Condition();
    public int TrueValue();
    public int FalseValue();
}
```

I would use classes and instead of referring to ints, I would refer to an `Expression` class too.

Answer (score 0):

How about rather than taking that approach you use something like Velocity? You basically read all the numbers in `left` in an array and all the numbers in `right` in a different array and pass these arrays to the Velocity context then let the user type a Velocity style if conditional and let Velocity take care of the rest ?